# How to properly add IO to attoparsec Parser?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, monad-transformers, attoparsec

I want to do some tracing/debugging in my attoparsec parser. Here's minimal [not] working example:

```
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
import Control.Applicative ((<*), (*>))

parseSentences :: Parser [T.Text]
parseSentences = many1 $ takeWhile1 (/= '.') <* char '.' <* skipSpace

parser :: Parser [T.Text] 
parser = do
    stuff <- parseSentences
--    putStrLn $ "Got stuff: " ++ show stuff

    tail <- takeText
--    putStrLn $ "Got tail: " ++ show tail

    return $ stuff ++ [tail, T.pack "more stuff"]

main = do
    let input = T.pack "sample. example. bang"
    print $ parseOnly parser input
```

What i have to do in order to use IO actions in my parser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had used the Parsec library, you would have had the possibility of using the Parsec monad transformer for mixing IO and parser commands in your code.

Attoparsec, however, is a pure parser, so you will have to use the [`Debug.Trace.trace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html#v%3atrace) function to output messages to the terminal for debugging purposes.

```
parser = do
  stuff <- parseSentences
  tail <- takeText
  return .
    trace ("Got stuff: " + show stuff) .
    trace ("Got tail: "  + show tail) $
    stuff ++ [tail, T.pack "more stuff"]
```

The messages will be printed when the associated value (here the result of the expression `stuff ++ ...`) is evaluated.

Comment: Ok, trace then. But how can i do them in between parser queries, like in original code? Is there a no-op thing to feed to trace and get an output from it?